# Describe $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} /\mathbb{3Z}\times\mathbb{Z} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I am trying to describe this quotient group $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{3Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ Let's denote with $A$ and $B$ respectively $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} $ and $\mathbb{3Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$

$A / B:= \{a+B : a \in A\}$ my problem is (might be a stupid one) there are infinity of $a \in A$ in form $(a_1,a_2)$  so i am confused about how to built that quotient group.

Comment: So for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n>0$ $(2n,z)$ are equivalent and also $(2n+1,z)$ are to each other ?

Comment: In the above comment what on earth does $>0$ have to do with the question? Why look at $2n$ and $2n+1$?

Comment: that was an answer to deleted comment I meant actualy the first component of the answer is equal to $\mathbb{Z_3}$ ?

Comment: So you mean $(\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z)/(3\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z)$, not $\mathbb Z\times (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)\times \mathbb Z$?

Comment: yes i meant first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lhf has given the right solution, but your comment suggests you don't understand it.

Here's a more elementary way.

We want to give a list of the distinct cosets $a+B$ - I use your notation.

When does $a+B=x+B$?. Answer, if and only if $a-x\in B$.

Taking $a=(m,n)$ and $x=(u,v)$ we have that these cosets are the same if and only if$(m-u,n-v)\in B=3\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.

That is $m=u$ is a multiple of $3$ and $n-v$ is any integer.

So for a set of cosets we can take the following set of 3 cosets : $\{(0,0)+B, (1,0)+B, (2,0)+B\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination. I understand now

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Consider $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ given by $(a,b) \mapsto a \bmod 3$. Find its kernel and its image.

Comment: So the kernel is $(\mathbb{3Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ and the image is $(\mathbb{Z_3},\mathbb{Z})$ am i right ?